# bitnami mariadb fails with Table 'mysql.db' doesn't exist

Tags: mariadb, bitnami

I spent a lot of time trying to debug and fix a database that was working without a problem few days earlier, and is refusing to start with:

```
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

after adding the env var:

```
- name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
  value: "true"
```

I can see that the real error is:

```
2021-07-14 23:12:32 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.db' doesn't exist
2021-07-14 23:12:32 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

crazy that bitnami hides these errors by default....

Answer (score 0):

Until now I couldn't figure out what broke it and how to really fix it, but I managed to start the database by exec into the container and running:

```
adduser mysql --uid=1001
chown mysql:root /opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb --datadir=/bitnami/mariadb/data
mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql --skip-external-locking --port=3306 --sock=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock --datadir=/bitnami/mariadb/data
```

After running the db I managed to run a `mysqldump`, copy all what is relevant for me, and reinstall a new db from scratch then restoring the content.

Why the user was not present and why I needed to change the permissions is beside me.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you were able to recover the database. I was going to suggest the `mysql_install_db` command as you mentioned, I am not sure if there is any other approach to solve that kind of issue. In any case, I think the ideal solution would pass through finding what causes the problem initially.